# How to monitor running programs with open ports?

Tags: shell-script, process, monitoring

Ok, so I want to monitoring running programs on Debian. For example I have a running several program on my instance and I can get output of `netstat -plnt` and see what is program and their ports. Example:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      65/sshd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      656/mysqld
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6379            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      631/redis-server
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1023/nginx
```

And I want receive a notification on email/slack when new program will be running. Maybe anybody know some utilities or program that can do it?

Comment: This seems more like a software-rec than a question. There's lots of monitoring tools, all with their own pros and cons: zabbix, checkmk, nagios, icinga...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bsh
#! /bin/bash

while :; do
    running=$(netstat -plnt)
    if [ "$running" != "$newrunning" -a -n "$firstrun" ]; then
        diff -u  <(echo "$newrunning") <(echo "$running") | mail -s "New listeners!" user@example.com
    fi
    newrunning=$(netstat -plnt)
    firstrun=1
    sleep 1
done
```

This script (must be run under root obviously) will notify you of any new/removed applications which open listening ports.

Answer (score 1):

This one allow you to set a list of apps

It can be added on cronjob

```
#!/bin/bash
known_apps="sshd|nginx|mysqld|redis"
netstat=$(netstat -plnt | awk 'FNR > 2' | egrep -v "$known_apps")

if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
   echo "other apps, running"
   send mail command including $netstat
fi
```

If you dont want a cronjob then instead of `if`, use `while`

```
while true;
do
   echo "other apps, running"
   sendmail command include $netstat 
   sleep 2  (or how often you want this loop to run )
done
```

It will just notify you about  new apps

Comment: It will spam your inbox continuously when new programs open listening ports.